# bundle install failing for ruby 2.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On running:

```
gem install bundler
```

Getting error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I am using ruby version 2.2.3.

Comment: Ruby version 2.3.3 is `eol (end-of-life): Branch is not supported by the ruby-core team any longer and does not receive any fixes. No further patch release will be released.` Do you really need to use Ruby 2.3.3?

Comment: yes, currently we are developing using the same.